# Adding styling to randomly generated Javascript numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to add styling (css) and have the ability to place some randomly generated numbers(%) anywhere I want (in a `<div>` to be more specific), but I don't know to achieve this.

These numbers are currently being placed at the complete end of each list items ( outside of main `<div>` but inside of the `<li>` ).

For clarity, here's a screenshot of 2 of the list items and how the number are being displayed: https://imgur.com/gsGRlaT

The html where the numbers are currently being displayed:

```
<div>
   {% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20" id="my_list">

          {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

          <li id="list_item">
              <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
                      <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
                      <h5>{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>
                      <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
               </div>

          <!--  Numbers are displayed randomly here --> 90%

          <!--  But I'm trying to display them in the div below -->

            <div class="numbers"> 90% </div>

          </li>

           {% endfor %}

       </ol>
</div>
    {% endif %}
```

And the Javascript code that generate the numbers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var orderedList = document.getElementById("my_list");
  var itemLength = 8; //REPLACE THIS WITH THE LENGTH OF THE ITEM LIST

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // get a default 100 into the array
  var arrayOfNumbers = [100],
      listItem = document.getElementById("list_item");

  // get itemLength random numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < itemLength; i++) {
    arrayOfNumbers.push(getRandomInt(30, 100))
  }

  // sort the array of random numbers
  arrayOfNumbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  })

  // now do the lopping and creating elements
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    let randomInt = document.createTextNode(arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%");
    listItem = document.getElementById("list_item");
    listItem.appendChild(randomInt);
    orderedList.appendChild(listItem);
  }

</script>
```

So how can I take control of how and where these numbers are placed?

Comment: Are you trying to have the numbers displayed at random positions within the `list_item`? What do you mean by adding styling to the numbers? Should all displayed number have same styling or suppose all same numbers (eg. all `91's`) should have particular style or all numbers should have random style?

Comment: What I'm trying to do Is create a `<div> ` element like this `<div class="numbers"><\div> ` (inside of every item) and have the numbers inside of that element so that I can use the `numbers` class to add styling to all the numbers.

Comment: Every Item inside the list will have the same `class="numbers"`.

Comment: Updated the question and added a section in the html for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost to the solution. Just a few minor modifications.

Create a `div` in place of where you create text node and add the class `numbers` to the created div. And you are done.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    let randomIntContainer = document.createElement('div');
    randomIntContainer.textContent = arrayOfNumbers[i] + "%";
    randomIntContainer.setAttribute('class', 'number');
    listItem = document.getElementById("list_item");
    listItem.appendChild(randomIntContainer);
    orderedList.appendChild(listItem);
  }
```

Comment: The results are not showing up and I get this error in my console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: randomInt is not defined`

Comment: My bad. I made a typo in my previous version. Please check the solution now.

Comment: Alright so I change this line to this: `listItem.appendChild(randomInt);` to this: `listItem.appendChild(randomIntText);` but no `<div>` have been created..

Comment: Okay so the change have been applied but the numbers are not being displayed anymore, I'm getting this instead: `[object Text]`.

Comment: I am making this really bad for you. I made multiple edits to the solution. Please try the updated one. Apologies.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help. Just a little problem left, I tried to add css like this `.number {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}` but there's no change..

Comment: Is there a way to actually create a `<div>` (without Javascript) and tweak the JS code so that I can call the function within this `<div>`?

Comment: You can either create a div normally in html (like you must have done for `list_item`). Or the second way is creating it through Javascript. So apart from that, you cannot manipulate html elements. And the point that the css style rules were not applied is very strange. You can cross check for typos/inspect the element and see if style rules are applied... Also you won't want to change your implementation just because your styling doesn't work.

Comment: Okay so I made it work. I forgot that I need to clear my cache in order to see the changes. Last thing: Is there a way to choose the position of the <div> created with Javascript? Because the <div> is positioned at the bottom of every items and I would like the numbers to be displayed below the Item's title and on top of the Image, see this screenshot for reference: imgur.com/xPFRgW0

Comment: Current you are selecting the list item: `document.getElementById("list_item");` and the adding the div with number as a child of it: `listItem.appendChild(randomIntContainer);`. If you want the number's div to be shown below destination, add an id to h5 <h5 id="imageDestination">{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>` and add the created div as a child to `imageDestination`.

Comment: Just try modifying the code and let me know if it fails to work.

Comment: Thanks, okay I will try!

Comment: So I tried changing the code to this: `matchingScore = document.getElementById("matching_score");
    matchingScore.appendChild(randomIntContainer);
    orderedList.appendChild(matchingScore);` And I added a new div with the Id of matching_score at the desired place.

Comment: But the numbers are not being displayed inside of every items anymore, they are all being displayed outside of the Li at the complete end of my page.